# Bitcoin Mining: Building a block

Tags: hash, bitcoin, blockchain, mining

I am not able to figure out how to build a hexadecimal block, if I have all the needed information (Hash, Merkel Root, etc.).

Please use this JSON formatted block as reference: [Block #506398](https://blockchain.info/block/00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048?format=json)

I understand the first 64 bytes are the block header, however what about the rest of the bytes?

Thanks For Your Help!

Comment: I am not able to figure out what to do

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some articles about bitcoin block structure:

- https://medium.com/all-things-ledger/bitcoins-implementation-of-blockchain-2be713f662c2
- https://medium.com/crypto-currently/lets-build-the-tiniest-blockchain-e70965a248b
- https://medium.com/capital-one-developers/bitcoin-blockchain-and-building-blocks-9f304380c77d

Please keep in mind that JSON is not compatible with bitcoin protocol. It is a easy to read representation of original block.